# Language setup in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, language-translation

I want to have user defined language translation setup in MVC.

My requirement is

Create Keyword

Enter Keyword: **Keyword_Name**

English:    **Name**

Danish :    **Navn**

Swedish :   **namn**

Icelandic:  **heiti**

User will create keyword and will give respective language text.

I want to fetch from DB these texts into my HTML page from keyword.

I need to have DB stuff with set of tables but I am considering Direct DB Connection for page load event with these structure will cause performance issue in application workflow.

So Any one used this idea before can help me out to acheive the result.

Comment: All you are doing is saving a record into the db and maybe reading it out from the db. There are plenty of examples online on how to do that.

Comment: Why do you care about performance if you have not done it yet? Creating db connections from your view is bad design and you should avoid it before you even consider performance. Follow [this](http://kristianguevara.net/creating-your-asp-net-mvc-5-application-from-scratch-for-beginners-using-entity-framework-6-and-identity-with-crud-functionalities/) tutorial

Comment: Yeah, But I didn't mean like calling DB from view.  Okay. I will have a UI and DB Structure and will get back to you if any issue comes.